# Spring & Hibernate - Error when using @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, controller, javabeans

I have an application setup based on a previous configuration - which was 100% functional. Now I am using maven and am encountering an Error in my controller class which says i must configure Beans.xml.

I'm not sure exactly what this means, as I have my dispatcher-servlet.xml configured in the same way as the functional application.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.me.test.controller"/>

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/userDB"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.me.test.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Edit: Screenshot of error. Which occurs when using the @Transactional annotation.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the complete stack trace and your disptacher-servlet.xml?

Comment: You get an error and are not sure what it means. So you ask us. But how could we know what it means if you don't post the error?

Comment: Guys I should clarify, its not a compile time error, it is an error in netbeans stating I should add a Beans.xml file..........

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the error to be more clear.

Comment: Take a look at this. Seems to be netbeans issue. https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=203710